# GPO Policy 'Applied' but not taking effect unless gpupdate /force is run

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, group-policy, internet-explorer

I do not yet have a 2012 DC or a Win 8 machine to manage IE 10 / 11 settings via GPMC. So I have created a policy with a registry setting so that users in a specific OU get specific .PAC settings in IE 11.

This is a user policy - that is linked and enforced at the specific OU level. It is the last processed User Policy. It appears in the top `GPRESULT` command on the workstations, however the policy is not listed below the policy list when you run with a `/v` for verbose - is this because it is a registry change? Or part of the issue?

I can see the policy being found, downloaded AND applied in the GP logs on multiple workstations. There no errors from any system for me to track down.

If I open IE after logging on (with an account in the specific OU), I do not see the settings for the PAC file. If I close IE and run `GPUPDATE /Force`, I can open IE and see the settings and note that they do work.

The policy is only for users in this OU, it is set for Authenticated Users as it applies to all users in the OU - though I have added a few test accounts for my use.

Answer (score 1):

the simple solution in this case would be running the gpupdate /force command throughout the specified OU. although i'm eager to know if you found another solution.

Comment: Depending on the number of affected users (<10?), this could be 100% the most correct answer. :D

Comment: or reboot at least 2 time the Client, after first reboot the change is regionized after the second the rule will be applied, dont know why Ms did that way but it works

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a 2012 domain controller or functional level to get newer Group Policy settings. You can get the newer ADMX/ADML files from Microsoft and install them into SYSVOL. They are backwards compatible.

[Microsoft Downloads: ADMX for IE 11](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40905)

As for the nuts and bolts of what you're trying to do an the issues you're encountering: What method are you using to apply settings into the Registry from Group Policy?  GPP? logon script?

[MS Technet reference for Group Policy processing and precedence](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785665%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  This doesn't go into how registry changes are handled, but it is useful reference.